Handle Notification Click Event on Safari iOS
I finally got Web Push Notifications to work on all platforms. But Apple as always need to make things more complicated than it should be and dont support click events on the notifications (see link below).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/click_event#browser_compatibility
Does anyone of you know a way around this? The main idea is to navigate the user to a specific page after clicking the notification - just like MDN shows in the docs (see link below)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients
The link above shows full support for client methods on Safari iOS. When will these methods ever be used if you dont know if the user has interacted with your notification? Seems like there is something I'm missing here The one I got my eyes on is focus() and openWindow()
Hacky solutions are more than welcome 
Thanks in advanced!
